# Error in IMAPISession::OpenMsgStore: MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER

Tags: outlook-redemption

i am trying to setup my window service on windows 2019 server with outlook 365 and getting below error. same code is running fine on windows server 2012 with outlook 365.Window service and outlook running on same service account which has admin access on server.

Error in Email Download service: Error in IMAPISession::OpenMsgStore: MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER
ulVersion: 0
Error: Microsoft Exchange is not available.  Either there are network problems or the Exchange server is down for maintenance.
Component: Microsoft Exchange Information Store

Code we are using:

#region  Mail Box Login
`        //Creating new Redemption Mail Session.
RDOSession objMailSession = new RDOSession();
CMTrace.WriteLine("Initiated new Redemption mail session");

```
            //Setting default folder.
            rdoDefaultFolders objInboxFolder = rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox;
            CMTrace.WriteLine("Initializing the default folder of Outlook as Inbox");

            //Login to Exchange Mail Box.
            objMailSession.Logon("", "", false, false, null, false);
            CMTrace.WriteLine("Logged in to Outlook Exchange Mail Box successfully");

            //Set Email Inbox as Default Folder.
           ** RDOFolder objFolder = objMailSession.GetDefaultFolder(objInboxFolder);
            CMTrace.WriteLine("Inbox set as Default Folder.");**
```

`
the last line giving error while trying to setup inbox as default folder.

trying to read emails from outlook 365

Comment: Does the target mailbox use OAuth or basic auth?

Comment: This use oAUTH , we are using outlook 365. The same code is running on windows 2012 server with same mailbox.

Comment: OAuth tokes are stored on the per-user basis, and even if the user identity is the same, the security context (desktop app vs service) is different enough, and the tokens cannot be shared.

Comment: any solution for this? how can we solve this?, also i wonder how the same code can  running in OS2012 with o365, where also both outlook and window service running with same user account.

Comment: 2012 and 2019 are different enough to affect how the oauth tokens are shared. Does it work from a regular desktop app?

Comment: Code is running as a windows exe service and outlook 365 client is installed on the same server with same user account.

Comment: Yes, but the difference between the service and the UI app is significant enough under Windows 2019 so that token sharing no longer works.

Comment: Is there any solution for this, any code change that you can recommend?

Comment: As a test, can you run your code in an app rather than a service?

Comment: This is console app code so we cannot run this as a application.

Comment: But console app runs in the same security context as a UI app. The difference is between a service and everything else.

Comment: But our one is a exe, exe doesn’t have any UI.

Comment: It does not matter. What matters is how the executable launched.
But a service exe cannot run as a standalone app out of the box

Comment: we have install the exe on the server and it running it with the same user account credentials

Comment: installed as a service? Once again, even if the user account is the same, the security contexts are different between code running in as a GUI app (Outlook) and a service.

Comment: so how can we fix this in existing service, any changes that we can do using redemption?

Comment: I don't think you can - MS changed the way auth tokens are cached.

Comment: will this work in windows server 2016?.

Comment: I don't know. Can you try?